# Book about a kid who randomly gets powers and is taken in by a girl who works for something like the paranormal police

Tags: story-identification, books

So there was this book on Wattpad that was later published and you could buy it on Amazon. I believe it was called like Psych. I'm pretty sure the authors name started with a P.

So this kid randomly gets powers; they have like different categories of powers like telekinesis, strength, etc. And this girl works for like basically the paranormal police and takes him in. Then he has to go to a camp to help train his powers, but turns out he can use all the powers. I think there were like five groups.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year was the book published?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Like maybe 2014? Or 2012?